# Encoding json tags in go

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I'm trying to change encoding in json, and used both encoding/json and jsoniter. What I'm trying to accomplish is that if I supply a language, it will encode relevant field names as "name@lang" instead of "name". I've ben trying the following:

```
func registerFieldEncoder(field string) {
encoderFunc := func(p unsafe.Pointer, stream *jsoniter.Stream) {
    fmt.Print("test")
    str := *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(p))
    newstr := str + "@sv"
    stream.WriteString(newstr)
}
isEmptyFunc := func(p unsafe.Pointer) bool {
    str := *(*string)(unsafe.Pointer(p))
    return len(str) == 0
}
jsoniter.RegisterTypeEncoderFunc(field, encoderFunc, isEmptyFunc)
jsoniter.RegisterFieldEncoderFunc("", field, encoderFunc, isEmptyFunc) }
```

The field represents the json tag, i.e.

```
`json:"field`
```

Is this possible to accomplish in go?

Answer (score 0):

Unmarshall the json as `map[string]interface{}`

write a function that recurses into the `map[string]interface` looking for keys called "name"

copy these keys to "name@lang" in the same map and then delete the "name" key

Marshall the modified map out again

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I considered this, however I feel like it would create a lot of roundabouts between marshalling and unmarshalling(object -> json -> map -> modify -> json). I know it is possible to accomplish this in C# as the JSON library allows quite a lot of leeway, but I couldn't manage it in GO; perhaps forking the json library is also a possibility.